# How to find which objects are listening to my event?

Tags: c#, events, listener

I have a class with an event:

```
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

Is there any way of getting a handle to the collection of objects (by reflection or otherwise) that are listening to this event?

**EDIT** - Um, sorry to move the goalposts - I **need** to be able to do this using reflection bc  I have a string value representing the event name, and I need to find the listeners.  I can't see an obvious way of accessing the GetInvocationList property using reflection...

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note: this is typically something that your code should not need to be aware of. There may be other ways to solve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up/1129530#1129530.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<object> targets = MyEvent.GetInvocationList().Select(d => d.Target).ToList();
```

Doing this via reflection will be somewhat obfuscated, if even possible, unfortunately, because this syntax:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

...

```
MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Is syntactic sugar. What this actually does is:

```
private EventHandler compilerGeneratedName;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { compilerGeneratedName += value; }
    remove { compilerGeneratedName -= value; }
}
```

...

```
compilerGeneratedName(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

In other words, events have always had the declarative shorthand that properties only recently received. As a result, in order to get at the invocation list you'll have to inspect the private variable, which is named by the compiler (unless, of course, you use the longhand syntax yourself and *know* the name of the instance variable).

There is no direct way to associate an externally exposed `event` construct with a backing handler any more than there is a direct way to tie a `property` to a backing variable: namely because *there isn't necessarily a one-to-one relationship*. Very likely there is, but as a rule it doesn't have to be that way.

You can try using reflection to inspect the private variables that are of the proper `EventHandler<>` type on the type that declares the event (note that you'll have to do it at the *specific type* that declares the event, *not* on a subclass) and see if you can determine some sort of correlation with the names, but this will be an unreliable solution at best.

Comment: +! good answer - please could you add in how to do this using reflection, as per my updated question?

Comment: Note: `GetInvocationList()` can only be called from within the class where the event is defined.

Comment: @Steve: If you're referring to using the event name directly, then you're correct. This is the same issue that I described, where the event name serves as an "alias" of sorts against the compiler-generated backing delegate when used within the declaring class.

Answer (score 0):

```
MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList()
```