# How do I make sure no handlers are attached to an event?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am adding an **event handler** like this:

```
theImage.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(theImage_MouseMove);
```

but in my application, this code gets run **every time** the page is shown, so I want to attach the event handler only **once**, but **how can I tell if a handler has been set yet or not, something like this:**

```
if(theImage.MouseMove == null) //error
    theImage.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(theImage_MouseMove);
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up

Comment: @Jason: Edward only cares about making sure the event isn't attached more than once, so the solutions to Edward's issue are different.

Comment: @Jason: Calling it a dupe makes more work, since it tempts me to open the question to verify if it is a dupe (in order to vote to close, if it is a dupe).

Answer (score 1):

I might me missing something, but if you just want to make sure that the handle is only called once, why don't you use `-=` before adding it. Something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new Timer(1000);

    timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

    timer.Start();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hit!");
}
```

The handler will only run once every second.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it down if you only want to attach once:

```
theImage.MouseMove -= theImage_MouseMove; //If it wasn't attached, doesn't matter
theImage.MouseMove += theImage_MouseMove;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but the way I usually do this is to simply use an unsubscribe before the subscribe.

If you do something like:

```
TheImage.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(theImage_MouseMove);
TheImage.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(theImage_MouseMove);
```

It will only ever get added once. If it doesn't already exist (the first time it's triggered), the -= doesn't hurt anything if it hasn't been subscribed to previously.

Answer (score -1):

```
theImage.MouseMove.GetInvocationList().Length
```

Comment: This doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up/1129530#1129530

Comment: for me it returns 3 (but didn't test it with mousemove)


public static EventHandler ee;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ee += (s, e) => { };
            ee += (s, e) => { };
            ee += (s, e) => { };
            Console.WriteLine(ee.GetInvocationList().Count());
            Console.Read();
        }

Comment: That's because you're working directly on the ee delegate, not an event published by another class.

Comment: Well that's not true !!  (sorry for the indentation, don't know how to make it)

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 mc = new Class1();
            mc.ee += (s, e) => { };
            mc.ee += (s, e) => { };
            mc.ee += (s, e) => { };
            Console.WriteLine(mc.ee.GetInvocationList().Count());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class Class1
    {
        public  EventHandler ee;
    }
but onmouse over is event and not delegate this is why you don't have GetInvocationList