# Is it possible to Remove a VB.NET EventHandler that your class didn't Add?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my VB.NET application, the event `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` has a handler subscribed to it.  The `ResolveEventHandler` which is subscribed to this event was added upstream from my code (for all I know, `System.AppDomain` has its own `Private Method` subscribed to the Event)...  is it possible to Remove all handlers from this event, so that I can add my own handler and ensure it's the **only one**?

Essentially I'm trying to do this:

```
RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf ClassX.MethodX
```

But I don't know what `ClassX` or `MethodX` are in this example because I haven't added a handler to this event yet, and this handler was added by upstream code.  I'm using the method described here to check if any handler is subscribed event:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953318/734914

**Edit:** I was able to figure out which method is subscribed to the event, using the Immediate Window while debugging.

```
?  DirectCast(gettype(System.AppDomain).GetField("AssemblyResolve", BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(AppDomain.CurrentDomain) , ResolveEventHandler)
{System.ResolveEventHandler}
    _methodBase: Nothing
    _methodPtr: 157334028
    _methodPtrAux: 1827519884
    _target: {System.ResolveEventHandler}
    **Method: {System.Reflection.Assembly ResolveAssembly**(System.Object, System.ResolveEventArgs)}
    Target: Nothing
```

Now I'm trying to Remove it, like this, because it's not a Public method:

```
RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf GetType(Reflection.Assembly).GetMethod("ResolveAssembly")
```

But that gives a compiler error saying: "AddressOf parameter must be the name of a method". So I'm not sure how to specify a non-Public method here

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that.

Comment: is this winforms app or a class lib?

Comment: my code is in a ClassLibrary that's loaded by a WinForms application

Comment: Here's a topic about removing delegates from events you don't have the delegate signature to: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/277477-remove-event-handler-without .. pretty handy, but at the end the poster stated that `"It looks like AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve doesn't support removal of events at all so the code I posted won't work."` .. even .NET complains with `The event 'System.AppDomain.AssemblyResolve' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=` (`+=/-=` are the C# `AddHandler/RemoveHandler`) .. so it's looking like a 'no' :/

Comment: txttechhelp - this code from your link was exactly what i needed.  please post your response as an answer so i can mark it as accepted.  GetInvocationList(), and info.GetRemoveMethod().Invoke( ... )

Comment: @txtechhelp: I don't think you ever saw OP's comment that asked you to post your comment as an answer.  I would suggest you still do so.

Comment: @sstan, thanks for the tagging, have added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the original comment:

[Here's](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/277477-remove-event-handler-without) a topic about removing delegates from events you don't have the delegate signature to .. pretty handy, but at the end the poster stated

> "It looks like AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve doesn't support removal of events at all so the code I posted won't work."

Even .NET complains that the event `System.AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=` (`+=/-=` operators are the C# `AddHandler/RemoveHandler`) .. so it's looking like a 'no' :/

Additionally, after your edits, the reason you can't do the following:

```
RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf GetType(Reflection.Assembly).GetMethod("ResolveAssembly")
```

Is because the [`AddressOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword is an operator keyword, similar to a `+` or `-` being an operator, the `AddressOf` operates on the procedure given and it must be a procedure name it can deduce at compile time. And the [`GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx) function returns a [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) type and not a known function address.

**All is not lost however!**

The [`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`RemoveHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) functions actually call for an `Object` and `Delegate` to be passed in (`AddressOf` gets compiled into a `Delegate` when used), so you don't need the `AddressOf` to do what you want, you need a [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twsk0311%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

To do this we can use the [`CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which *does* take a `MethodInfo` object. It should be noted that since you're trying to access private methods, you'll need to specify the [`BindFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance` and `Reflection.BindFlags.NonPublic` (I say `and` but you'll do a bitwise `Or` on them), example:

```
GetType(Reflection.Assembly).GetMethod("ResolveAssembly", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

So calling `CreateDelegate` on this will give us the following code

```
[Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Reflection.Assembly), GetType(Reflection.Assembly).GetMethod("ResolveAssembly", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic))
```

But that's rather verbose, so lets break it down:

```
Dim type As Type = GetType(Reflection.Assembly)
Dim mi As Reflection.MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("ResolveAssembly", (Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic))
```

And now we can simply call the `RemoveHandler` on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` via the following:

```
RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, [Delegate].CreateDelegate(type, mi)
```

Except `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` expects delegate/event signatures to match, so we need to cast our created delegate to the appropriate type:

```
RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, CType([Delegate].CreateDelegate(type, mi), System.ResolveEventHandler)
```

And you can now remove a private method through reflection from the event handler.

**WARNING!!**
While this code will compile and run, I make no guarantees of it's validity or accuracy since you're mucking with frame and stack pointers (essentially), and so while it *might* run and it *might* work, it also *might* spawn baby kittens .. so just be careful.

Hope that can help!