# Passing delegate as method parameter

Tags: c#, events, parameters, delegates

I'm currently developing an EventManager class to ensure that no events are left wired to dead WCF duplex clients, and also to control prevent multiple wiring from the same client to the one event.

Now basically, I'm what stuck with is trying to pass the event delegate to a function that will control the assignment like this.

```
var handler = new SomeEventHandler(MyHandler);
Wire(myObject.SomeEventDelegate, handler);
```

To call this:

```
private void Wire(Delegate eventDelegate, Delegate handler)
{
    // Pre validate the subscription.
    eventDelegate = Delegate.Combine(eventDelegate, handler);
    // Post actions (storing subscribed event delegates in a list)
}
```

**Update**

The code for SomeEventDelegate wrapper is:

```
public Delegate SomeEventDelegate
{
    get { return SomeEvent; }
    set { SomeEvent = (SomeEventHandler) value; }
}

event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;
```

Obviously the delegate is not being returned to the myObject.SomeEventDelegate
And I cannot return the Delegate from the method because I need some validation after too.
Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: you can combine delegates using +=

Comment: C# events generate a hidden delegate for you.  To access this event, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up/1129530#1129530.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [C# `ref` parameter modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
var handler = new SomeEventHandler(MyHandler);
Wire(ref myObject.SomeEventDelegate, handler);

private void Wire(ref Delegate eventDelegate, Delegate handler)
{
    // Pre validate the subscription.
    eventDelegate = Delegate.Combine(eventDelegate, handler);
    // Post actions (storing subscribed event handlers in a list)
}
```

Note also that there exists some nice syntactic sugar (as of C# 2.0) for assigning and combining delegates (see [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html), for example):

```
Wire(ref myObject.SomeEventDelegate, MyHandler);

private void Wire(ref Delegate eventDelegate, Delegate handler)
{
    // Pre validate the subscription.
    eventDelegate += handler;
    // Post actions (storing subscribed event handlers in a list)
}
```

It has been pointed out to me that `ref` only works with fields, not properties. In the case of a property, an intermediary variable can be used:

```
var tempDelegate = myObject.SomeEventDelegate;
Wire(ref tempDelegate, MyHandler);
myObject.SomeEventDelegate = tempDelegate;
```

Comment: Note that it will only work if SomeeventDelegate is a field... Properties can't be passed as ref parameters

Comment: hi there, the ref keyword doesn't work here because the myObject.SomeEventDelegate is just a wrapper property to make the event delegate accessible outside the its class.

Comment: @Thomas: Ah, good point. I had forgotten about that. In that case, an intermediary variable can be used. Editing...

Comment: Ok, I believe it works now! I changed the event declaration following the Steve Guidi suggestion and after I could use the ref keyword. Thank you all for your help!