# Anonymous delegate as function parameter

Tags: c#, anonymous-delegates

I'm trying to pass parameter, which is anonymous delegate (no input parameters, no return value), to function.

Something like this:

```
private function DoSomething(delegate cmd)
{
     cmd();
}
```

Then, I'm want to use this function to call function in this way:

```
DoSomething(delegate
{
     Console.WriteLine("Hooah!");
});
```

I'm want this specific way, because it's **easy to use** writing style.

Possible?

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx to see how delegates used as fucntion parameter

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938356/passing-delegate-as-method-parameter

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Exactly for such purposes Microsoft has created the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wrapper classes in the .NET framework. Both classes are relying on [anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx). Use Action if you don't need to return any result, just to execute the anonymous function:

```
private void DoSomething(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
DoSomething(() => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
});
```

The `() =>` term is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and means something like `input with no parameters is calling ...`. See the documentation for a thorough explanation.

If you want to return a result, then use the Func delegate:

```
private T DoSomething<T>(Func<T> actionWithResult)
{
    return actionWithResult();
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(DoSomething<int>(() => 
{
    return 100;
}));
```

Both wrappers have overrides that accept up to 8 parameters.

When using Func, the last parameter is always the return type:

```
// returns a string
Func<string> t = () => { return "test string"; };
// first parameter is of type int, result of type string
Func<int, string> toString = (id) => { return id.ToString(); };
// parameters are of type int and float, result is string
Func<int, float, string> sumToString = (n1, n2) => { return (n1 + n2).ToString(); };
```

The Func wrapper can be used directly with a typed parameter:

```
Func<string, string> up = text => text.ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine(up("test"));
```

I often use Func's in order to create a generic executor that is wrapped in a try/catch block and logging if something happens. This way i reduce the repetative code:

```
private T safeCallWithLog<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    try
    {           
        return action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Oops ...: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
    // return default type if an error occured
    return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = safeCallWithLog<DbEntry>(() =>
            {
                return databaseContext.GetEntryWithId(42);
            });

var id = safeCallWithLog<int>(() =>
                    {
                        return databaseContext.GetIdFor("J.D.");
                    });
```

You could still use the original [delegate concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx). The Action and the Func classes are just wrappers around [predefined generic delegate methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

```
// declare delegate contract
private delegate void output();
// create caller method
private void method(output fun)
{
    fun();
}
// some test functions, that must match exactly the delegate description
// return type and number of arguments
private void test1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}

private void test2()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

// call different methods
method(test1);
method(test2);
// inline call without hard coded method
method(delegate() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("inline");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

.NET has a bunch of these built in. `Action` is the one you want for no parameters and no return types:

```
private function DoSomething(Action cmd)
{
    cmd();
}
```

There's also a generic version(s) of Action if you want a delegate with parameters but no return types (e.g. `Action<int, int>` for a method that takes two ints and has no return).

`Func` and `Predicate` (along with generic versions for those too) also exist.

Answer (score 1):

However Pasty describe most possible solvings, I just want to add about the key word delegate.

- **The first case is - to declare new type:**

In the example it is used to describe an input parameter

```
private function DoSomething(delegate cmd)
{ 
     cmd();
}
```

But it can be used to declare object type that is used to contain a pointer to function:

```
public delegate *returnParameterType* NewTypeName(*inputParamType1* inputParam1, ...)
```

and then used that *NewTypeName* as a type for input parameter:

```
private function DoSomething(NewTypeName cmd)
    { 
         cmd();  
    }
```

- **The second case of usinf key word 'delegate' is like in your example - to declare anonymous method**

  delegate()
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Hooah!");
  }

However at that situation such method must be assigned or to suitable defined delegate either to generic delegate like Action, because Action isn't supposed to have output parameters

```
private void delegate Output();
Output func = delegate(){Console.WriteLine("Hooah!");}
```

or

```
Action func1 = delegate(){Console.WriteLine("Hooah!");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. For method without a return type use `Action` otherwise `Func<>`.

```
public void Function(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

and call it like

```
Function(() => System.Console.WriteLine("test"));
```

It's even more pleasant way using lambdas instead of the `delegate` keyword. You can even execute the action using `action.Invoke()`, but in my opinion it's better to call it like it's a method, which it is actually.