# Getting event handler from event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “steal” an event handler from one control and give it to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth)

Is there a way to get references of the event handlers from the event?

**For example:**

```
EventHandler evt = btn.Click; // or another way ?
```

(Here the `EventHandler` is the delegate and `Click` is an event of Button)

Comment: Just wondering what you are trying to achieve?....

Comment: An event only implements add and remove accessor blocks, like get and set only different.  As such, there is no "get" for events.  [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Comment: Found answer at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth

see post from Hans Passant

Comment: @user125697 I found answer in the suggested duplicate. See the answer from Hans Passant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth

Answer (score 2):

If you defined the event and your code that accesses it is in the same class (i.e. not derived) then you can access it and get the invocation list.

```
MulticastDelegate m = (MulticastDelegate)MyEvent;  

var list = m.GetInvocationList();  

foreach(Delegate d in list)  
{  
    // look at the delegate
}
```

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_events01292006081130AM/csharp_events.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/9a58321d-7fd5-45ca-bba0-44a0a336aeeb

For the case where you want to access the invocation list of an event defined in a class whose code you can't modify...

- [C# How to find if an event is hooked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-sharp-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up)

Answer (score -3):

You can try with this code - Just `casting`

```
var result = (EventHandler)control.Click;
Console.WriteLine(result.Method.Name);
```