# How to check if the object already has the a specify event set

Tags: c#

I have a class named `MifareReader`. I instantiate it as `Global`  So i Have on my form_load:

```
MifareReader mf = new MifareReader()

private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mf.MyEvent += new EventName(My_Method);
   Connect();  
}

private void My_Method()
{
  //Code Here
}

private void Connect()
{
  //Some Code Here
  mf.MyEvent += new EventName(My_Method); //The same code of the Main_Load
}
```

Now let me explain. On my `Main_Load` I've set the event `MyEvent` and set it's method to `My_Method` Right ? Also, I called the other method `Connect()`, this methods repeat what i've done on the `Main_Load`

```
mf.MyEvent += new EventName(My_Method);
```

Right ?

So, I don't know why, but if I do not repeat this code, the application DOES NOT fire the `MyEvent` without Closing/Reopening the application.

Ok, its working perfect the way it is, but when I close/reopen my application, it fires `MyEvent` twice. So, Is there a way to work around this ?
Maybe check if the `mf.MyEvent` has already a method set to it?

Comment: check [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129517/c-sharp-how-to-find-if-an-event-is-hooked-up)

Comment: It's possible verify if a method was set in a event, but first let me ask: If you delete the first set in `Main_Load` what happens?

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi My method `Connect()` is responsible to set a my rfdi device's configuration and save it on my app.config. I thought that, when there were already a config set, it would be necessary to have that code on my Main_Load. But it worked perfect removing that, Thank you Jonny !!!!! +1